# iText - Missing background color in table with rowspan and page break

Tags: java, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

I'm using [flying-saucer-pdf-itext5](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) (v 9.0.7) and [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/) (v 5.5.6) to generate PDF from given XHTML file. I have a big table in XHTML with a couple of rowspans and with CSS style (background color).

Simplified XHTML snippet:

```
<tr align="right">
    <th align="left" rowspan="16" style="background: silver;">United Kingdom</th>
    <th align="left" style="background: silver;">Ambleside</th>
    <td>38,726</td>
    <td>30,546</td>
</tr>
```

**This style is applied correctly for all rowspans, except one - which is split to 2 pages by page break (see picture)**.

[image]

What i'm doing wrong? Or it is a bug in flying-saucer / iText?