# iText 8 does not entirely fill background of a cell with rowspan > 1 which splits to the next page

Tags: c#, itext, cell

Only first row of the cell is filled with background color until next page. The remnant of the cell on the next page fills correctly.

I think this old question with zero answers is related:
[iText - Missing background color in table with rowspan and page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568471/itext-missing-background-color-in-table-with-rowspan-and-page-break)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGYBf.png)

Here is a sample C# code to reproduce the problem ( See Row 4 on the first page and Row 7 on the second page):

```
var f = CreateFileName();
var wri = new PdfWriter(f);
var pdoc = new PdfDocument(wri);
var doc = new Document(pdoc);
var table = new Table(2).SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
var color = ColorConstants.CYAN;
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    table.AddCell(new Cell(10, 1).SetBackgroundColor(color).Add(new Paragraph($"Row {i}")));
    for (int j = 1;j<=10; j++)
    {
        table.AddCell(new Cell().SetBackgroundColor(color).Add(new Paragraph($"Detail {j}")));
    }
    if (color == ColorConstants.GREEN)
        color = ColorConstants.CYAN;
    else
        color = ColorConstants.GREEN;
}
doc.Add(table);
doc.Close();
```